# Web font rendering in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm building a website for a business and to go with it they're totally rebranding, new logo and all. The logo features a stylish swishy font which I wanted to echo across the site in the page titles etc, so I took the ttf and ran it through font2web.com and put the generated versions of the font (eot, woff, svg etc) in to the site and the generated CSS @font-face rule in to my code and started using it. In IE, Firefox, Safari and Safari on iPad the font looks fine - although Safari is sort of borderline. But in Chrome? It looks absolutely awful, all the detail's lost and the letters just turn in to white blocks.

Here's a screenshot --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/016Kj.png

and here's my CSS (with Liquid tags) -->

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MotionPicture';
    src: url({{ 'MotionPicture.eot' | asset_url }});
    src: local('☺'), url({{ 'MotionPicture.woff' | asset_url }}) format('woff'), 
    url({{ 'MotionPicture.svg' | asset_url }}) format('svg'),
    url({{ 'MotionPicture.ttf' | asset_url }}) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you want the exact font you can get it here --> http://www.dafont.com/motion-picture.font

I tried a few tricks I found through Google, moving the SVG version to the top of the font-face because Chrome cant AA truetype fonts, but it didn't make a difference.

Is there any way this could look acceptable or will I have to resort to image-based headers, which I really don't want.

Cheers all,
-- Ben.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in Chrome on windows. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692

Answer (score 0):

Some css you could try

```
   -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
   -webkit-text-stroke: 0px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by forcing a redraw of the page ondomready.

Using jQuery:

```
$(function({
    $('#page').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#page').show();
    }, 0);
});
```